# How do I preserve MVC principles and make my website more unit-testing friendly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I've made a simple website in ASP.NET MVC Framework with users, articles etc., and images to users profiles. There is a simple static class for image manipulation (resizing, cropping and saving images on hard drive), placed in "Helper" directory. I wonder what to do with the code to preserve MVC principles and make whole website more unit testing friendly.

Grettings

Comment: How is it NOT unit-test-friendly now?

Comment: Becouse of dependecy. Controller class should not be dependent on any other class without ineterface.

Comment: You can always move the image manipulation code to another class library but I agree with Brandon...part of using MVC has to do with it's inherent unit testing functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Make the helper class non-static, declare it as argument of you controller constructor and inject it with a controller factory that uses dependency injection.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: What about it? I can answer yes or no, but I don't understand the reason of your question.

Comment: Your proposed approach seems a bit unorthodox for an asp.net mvc application.  I was just wondering if you actually use this approach in you own applications.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your controller not dependent on your image manipulation helper, you'll need to have it talk to an interface, rather than a concrete class. So make an interface like IImageManipulator, and have your controller call methods on that interface rather than on your class. Your image manipulator class will need to implement this interface. You'll need to use a dependency injection technique to get the concrete implementation injected into your controller (there are several acceptable ways to do this).

Now your controller will depend on an interface and not a concrete implementation, allowing you to unit test your controller by mocking the IImageManipulator interface and injecting that mock into the controller.